# Rotate only an extrusion

Tags: extrude

On this site:
http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?283909-ramp-modeling

Poster Kaluura gave an excellent demo of ramp building.  I've done a lot of complex shapes but I couldn't get the ramp to work and make the edges meet other objects in my scene properly.  This demo looks like it will do the trick and I understand most of the steps.  I'm actually stuck near the beginning however, because in step 2, he has a nice graphic and says "Extrude without moving. Rotate the extruded loopcut on the Z axis around the 3D cursor."

I can't seem to rotate the extruded face while leaving the original face in place.  Can someone more experienced and wiser translate this step for me?   Thanks.

Comment: Extrude (E), then cancel (RMB) then rotate (R).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You notice his cursor is offset to the left so when he rotates the face, it rotates around the cursor position instead of in-place.  To get that effect you need to make sure you are using 3D Cursor as your pivot point before rotating the face.  The button for pivot point is at the bottom of the 3D view next to the viewport shading button.

Comment: Another way (which I prefer) is to select the front faces of the ramp, go into top view then hold CTRL and left click in the view away from it, this will extrude those faces and rotate at the same time.  All you have to do then is CTRL+Left Click around the view and your track will be built much quicker.

Comment: Yeah, the 3D cursor is in the proper place.  I've set it up some distance away (1m) so that I can rotate the ramp around it as I build it.  The point is, when I press 'E' and escape, I can't then seem to rotate only the extruded edge.

And if possible, I'd like to do so with a dialogue box so I can specify the angle to rotate by.

Comment: OK, I found the problem.  I had changed the origin.  I usually change the origin of new objects to something I think is useful.  Somehow, the pivot center was not set to the origin though.  Instead it was set to the bounding box.  That's what kept throwing off my transformations.   Your answer pointed me in the right direction even though I had actually set the pivot point.   For future readers there is a button on the bottom called "Pivot Center for Rotation/Scaling.  You have to make sure this points to your objects origin.